# c# Remove duplicate code from multiple classes using generics or dependency injection

Tags: c#

I am stuck trying to remove duplicate code from some of my classes. I have a network app that uses local files to store "databases" of all kinds (user data, posts, project specific information etc). For each database I have created a `Serializable` class which holds all information and I have created a generic serializer class `EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<T>` to save and load these information from files on the disk (in an encrypted form).

For each type of database file, I have created a controller class which is responsible for finding the correct database file path and return or save an instance of the respective `Serializable` class from or to the database file.

These controller classes all share much of the same code and I am struggling to find a way to consolidate them. I was hoping someone could point me to the right direction, either by creating a generic controller class or a master controller class in which to inject one of the existing controllers?

```
public class EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<T>
{
    private string _filepath;

    public EncryptedDatabaseSerializer(string filepath)
    {
        _filepath = filepath;
    }
    
    private void SaveDatabase(T dataStructure)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        string backupFile = _filepath + ".bak";
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(_filepath))
            {
                // Back up file.
                File.Copy(_filepath, backupFile, overwrite: true);
                File.Delete(_filepath);
            }
            File.Delete(_filepath);
            
            using (var fs = new FileStream(_filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateEncryptor(Security.desKey, Security.desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, dataStructure);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(backupFile))
            {
                // Restore backup file.
                File.Copy(backupFile, _filepath, overwrite: true);
                File.Delete(backupFile);
            }

            throw new CouldNotSaveDatabase();
        }

        File.Delete(backupFile);
    }

    private T LoadDatabase()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_filepath))
        {
            throw new DatabaseFileNotFound();
        }

        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(_filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateDecryptor(Security.desKey, Security.desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new CouldNotLoadDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```

Two of my controller classes for reference:

```
public static class ProjectAssignedServicesController
{
    private const string projectAssignedServicesFileNameExtension = @"bft";

    // This controller requires a ProjectFolder to find the correct database file path.
    public static ProjectAssignedServices TryLoadProjectServices(ProjectFolder projectFolder)
    {
        string filePath = ServerConnection.GetDatabaseFilepathForProject(projectFolder, projectAssignedServicesFileNameExtension);

        EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<ProjectAssignedServices>  encryptedDbSerializer = 
            new EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<ProjectAssignedServices>(filePath);

        try
        {
            ProjectAssignedServices loadedServices = encryptedDbSerializer.TryLoadDatabase();
            return loadedServices;
        }
        catch (CouldNotLoadDatabase)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (DatabaseFileNotFound)
        {
            // If the assigned services file does not exist, create an empty database.
            return ProjectAssignedServices.CreateEmpty();
        }
    }

    public static bool TrySaveProjectServices(ProjectFolder projectFolder, ProjectAssignedServices projectAssignedServices)
    {
        string filePath = ServerConnection.GetDatabaseFilepathForProject(projectFolder, projectAssignedServicesFileNameExtension);
        
        EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<ProjectAssignedServices> encryptedDbSerializer =
            new EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<ProjectAssignedServices>(filePath);

        try
        {   
            encryptedDbSerializer.TrySaveDatabase(projectAssignedServices);
            return true;
        }
        catch (CouldNotSaveDatabase)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static class ProjectServicesController
{
    private const string projectServicesFile = @"project_services.db";

    // This controller accesses a specific file.
    public static string getServicesFileFilepath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(ServerConnection.serverFolder, projectServicesFile);
    }

    public static RadinProjectServices TryLoadProjectServices()
    {
        EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<RadinProjectServices>  encryptedDbSerializer = 
            new EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<RadinProjectServices>(getServicesFileFilepath());

        try
        {
            RadinProjectServices loadedServices = encryptedDbSerializer.TryLoadDatabase();
            return loadedServices;
        }
        catch (CouldNotLoadDatabase)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (DatabaseFileNotFound)
        {
            return RadinProjectServices.CreateEmpty();
        }
    }

    public static bool TrySaveProjectServices(RadinProjectServices services)
    {
        EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<RadinProjectServices> encryptedDbSerializer =
            new EncryptedDatabaseSerializer<RadinProjectServices>(getServicesFileFilepath());

        try
        {   
            encryptedDbSerializer.TrySaveDatabase(services);
            return true;
        }
        catch (CouldNotSaveDatabase)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder since you haven't asked a question for a while, the title of the question should indicate what the code does rather than your concerns about the code. Keep in mind that we make suggestions about the code you post rather than answer specific questions.

Comment: The common way to reduce duplicate code between classes that perform similar actions is to have a common base class that all the other classes inherit from. You can do this with a base class and an interface. C# is an object oriented language, and allows inheritance.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226).

Answer (score 2):

> These controller classes all share much of the same code and I am struggling to find a way to consolidate them

To consolidate code you must see how things are the same and code as if they are the same, which they are. However you are thinking about how everything is different and writing code starting with those differences so you end up with customized code for what should be the same. For example the path/file.

**Think about how things are the same**

- // This controller accesses a specific file.
- // This controller requires a ProjectFolder to find the correct database file path.

Each controller needs a certain file - same thing. WHAT you should be doing is the same thing in each controller.  HOW it is done is the same. The steps are the same, only the DATA has changed.

**Overloading**

WHAT it is doing is a method name; the same method name.

HOW it is done is the same general steps.

DATA is different; method parameters may be different,
process sub-steps may need to do more, less, the same, or nothing at all.

Maybe do this using subclassing with polymorphism, maybe delegates, maybe both. That depends on how domain data and processes can be conceptualized, abstracted. That is to say the software/class design.